# CSS image haywire

Tags: css

Can someone help me out with some css image positioning?

I am trying to make a column where the top and bottom are separate images. I am 
doing this so I will have a nice curve but when the images are placed in, the right column
goes underneath the left div instead of floating right. I have tried absolute positioning but seems to do nothing. Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

CSS:

```
#column-top{
    width:735px;
    height:40px;
    float:left;
    background-image:url(images/opactop.png);
}

#column_left_content{
    width:735px;
    min-height:500px;
    margin-right:0px;
    float:left;
    background-image:url(images/opaccontent.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
}

#column_bottom{
    width:735px;
    height:40px;
    float:left;
    background-image:url(images/opacbottom.png);   
}


#column_right{
    width:160px;
    height:900px;
    float:right;
    background-image:url(images/opac.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
```

Comment: Since you're new, I'll clarify the above comment: a live demo will be helpful. http://www.jsfiddle.com allows you to make quick demos.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my fiddle for you.  You don't need to float the top and bottom.  left float the two middle ones and place them inside a container div.  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwfiorini/BT586/)

Comment: thanks ryan for going to the trouble on jsfiddle. it works grand with the colours but when i put in the background images the right column shoots down the bottom again.

Comment: I updated my fiddle to use images in the background and it is still staying to the right.   The trick is make sure the width of the left and right columns don't exceed the width of the parent container it is in.  When the combined widths exceed the parent the right will be pushed to the bottom.